# Redirect to a menu item from controller

Tags: joomla-3.4, menu-item, redirect

I have a configuration variable which a menu item type where admin can select a menu item. This is used to redirect the front end user if he doesn't have access to the view.

In the component controller file I do the access validation and now I want to redirect to the menu item.

How can I do the redirection to a particular menu item with proper Itemid?

Answer (score 2):

I do it this way (providing you know the Itemid)

```
$app    = JFactory::getApplication();
$menu   = $app->getMenu();

$item           = $menu->getItem($Itemid);
$params         = $item->params;
$return_menu_id = $params->get('return_menu_id ');
$return_item    = $menu->getItem($return_menu_id);  
$return_menu    = JRoute::_($return_item->link.'&Itemid='.$return_item->id);
$app->redirect($return_menu);
```

Hope this work for you too

Answer (score 2):

If you are in controller and have Itemid from component configuration, you can try this simple redirect:

```
$this->redirect(JRoute::_('index.php?Itemid=' .JComponentHelper::getParams('com_yourcomponent')->get('login_itemid')))
```

if you have sef it will be used otherwise it will be used a `link` url from menu item.